# Find the volume obtained by totating the area formed by $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$ about $y=1$

Tags: calculus, volume, applications

The questions asks us to find the volume of solid formed when the area between $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$ is rotated about the line $y=1$.

I understand that a cone is formed. Now, to find the volume, I integrate from $0$ to $2$, $f(y)=\pi(y^2-y^4)$. (I understand that a ring is formed when we take a cross section, therefore, area of outer radius minus inner radius).

Where am I going wrong? I am getting a wrong answer.

Comment: The distance between the x-axis and a point on one of the curves is |y| not |x|.

Comment: Shouldn't you be integrating from 0 to 1?

Comment: @randomgirl It means that I have taken the distance from x axis and I need to take the distance of the graph (radius) from y = 1?

Comment: Yeah you dealing with vertical distances not horizontal distances since the axis of rotation is horizontal.

Comment: Radius would be something like $1-y$ where you replace the $y$ there in terms of x.... You have two circles to consider.

Comment: @browngreen I think that you're right. I should integrate from 0 to 1. That was also a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use the washer method, shell method, or something else?

Comment: @browngreen washer method I think.

Comment: @randomgirl can you give me the final equation? I have the two radius as (1-y) and (1-y^2). Correct?

Comment: radius of small circle would be $(1-x)$ and radius of big circle would be $(1-\sqrt{x})$

Comment: got it. I was still using y. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I said that backwards... I just realized.

Comment: radius of small circle would be $(1-\sqrt{x})$ and radius of big circle would be $(1-x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the washer method, you would integrate in terms of $x$ from 0 to 1, with the larger radius being $1-x$ and the smaller radius being $1-\sqrt x$.  This gives the equation $$ \int_0^1 \pi ((1-x)^2-(1-\sqrt x)^2)dx $$